# How to get current and next three days with month details ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to get the current and next three days with month details in iOS application.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely possible.

Comment: I have tried to get current week and next week details.  If have any sample please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = 1; // Here add your days

    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *nextDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];


    NSLog(@"nextDate: %@ ...", nextDate);
```

Month info:

```
    unsigned units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate: nextDate];
    // get your month
    NSInteger month = [components month];
```